# understanding DRC errors in ares proteus

Tags: pcb-design, proteus

i'm new to PCB and this my first printed circuit , i cannot understand what the DRC error is telling me , could you help to better read the error log and also help me with this error [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [clearance rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82935/clearance-rules-for-outer-inner-layers), specified as 10 thou (the default rule).

On layer I3 in the design, you have a pad *overlapping* a track or another pad by 6 thou (hence the -6 in the *Actual clearance* column). The pad in question is highlighted.

The rule highlights errors from different nets.

In this case, you appear to have connected the pad highlighted to a track to pin 7, but the ratsnest shows this should be connected to pin 4.